# Does pause() block a process "unconditionally" or ''in a wait queue"?

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

In operating system concepts, `pause()` blocks a process "either unconditionally" or "in a wait-queue".  I'm confused between the two.
I think it can do both; however, I am not sure.

Comment: You should probably specify that you're thinking of the POSIX [`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) function (if, indeed, that is what you're thinking of — otherwise specify more precisely what you _are_ thinking of).

Comment: If you're thinking of POSIX `pause()`, then it blocks a thread (possibly the only thread in a single-threaded process) unconditionally, putting it into a kernel wait queue, waiting for a signal to wake it.  So "both" seems reasonable to me.